# ssh -R make target host accept connection on all interfaces

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a SOURCE host which is remote and behind NAT.
I want to connect to SOURCE via ssh from a TARGET host which is in my home network.
Thus I issue the following command on SOURCE:

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 TARGET -N
```

Now from TARGET I can connect to SOURCE via `ssh -p 2222 localhost`. Fine

With TABLET in the same network of TARGET I would expect this to work:

```
ssh -p 2222 TARGET
```

Instead it looks like TARGET only accept connections on port 2222 from localhost. The following is on TARGET:

```
user@TARGET:~/$ netstat -l | grep 2222
tcp        0      0 localhost:2222          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:2222          [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Is there a way to make the remote side of a `ssh -R` accept connections from all its interfaces?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, it will listen on localhost (loopback interface) only. You need to specify the bind_address as `0.0.0.0` in your command:

```
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22 TARGET -N
```

You need also to configure SSH daemon on target host to allow client to specify the bind_address. It is prohibited by default to listen to all interfaces. So, you will always find it listening on loopback even if you specifiy `0.0.0.0` as bind_address.

You need to have a line like the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow client to specify the bind address.

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

When done, you can verify using `netstat -lntp` on target machine.

Comment: Actually I already tried that, but with no success. Does this work for you? This is the output: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - ` - `tcp6       0      0 ::1:2222                :::*                    LISTEN      -`

Comment: Anyway I thought that the HOST in PORT:HOST:PORT was referring from caller side

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, my answer was not complete. I updated it!

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know about the HOST:PORT:HOST:PORT syntax. Very useful. Also sshd configuration was missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually `0.0.0.0` at the beginning of a parameter can be omitted. This is a shortcut. It means that `-R :2222:localhost:22` will do the same. Please note and don't forget semicolon right before `2222`.

Comment: Thanks and if you want to listen on all interfaces (both IPv4 and IPv6), I read you have to use something like `ssh -R \*:2222:localhost:22 user@remote.server.ip.address`. Source: https://www.linuxwave.info/2020/08/ssh-tunnelling-to-bind-on-all-interfaces.html
Maybe it has the same effect as @VictorYarema comment?
Edit: in fact I did not need to listen on all interfaces, localhost was enough to use reverse VNC if I use local port forwarding on the server and remote port forwarding on the client. It have the advantage to use an end-to-end SSH tunnel to secure VNC.

Comment: Actually "-R :2222:localhost:22" is not the same as "-R 0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22", the latter only listens for IPv4 addresses whereas the former listens for all IPv4 AND IPv6 addresses.